# Scroll to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have few `div`s `.posts` which have a *attr* `data-id` which corresponds to the `mysql DB id`.

```
<div class="posts" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="posts" data-id="2"></div>
```

Now if I want to scroll to a specific `div` which I am only known to the `data-id`.
How will I scroll to it?.
My [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz54d/).
Can anyone give an example along with a JSFiddle?

Comment: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use link anchors and JQuery.
Just give your link the class "scroll" and use the following code in the head:

```js
$(function() {
  // Listen for a click event on the anchor
  $('.scroll').click(function(event) {
  
    // Prevent the jump to target that is default browser behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Animate the scrollTop property of the scrollParent to the top offset 
    // of the target element. In this case, we have an animation duration of 1000ms(1 second).
    $('html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Just for demo purposes */
.post {
  margin: 100vh 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#anchor" class="scroll">Go To Div 8</a>
<div class="post" id="anchor">Scroll to me</div>
```

Comment: Adding preventDefault is not always a healthy practice, it might break other functionality. Avoid that

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is added to remove the default function of the anchor, if you do not add it, the anchor will add to the navigation(`http://example.com/#anchor`) and could have a buggy rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery.ScrollTo plugin: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

In this link you can find demos http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

```
$(function() {             
    $('body').scrollTo($('div[data-id=1]'), 1000); //scroll to div 1        
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="posts" data-id="1"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide code to demonstrate the use of this plugin. Right now, it is not very useful, as the links (especially the demo link) could rot and we'd be left with not very much of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript if you have an anchor with a `name`.

`<a href="#post8">Div to post 8</a>` scrolls to `<a name="post8"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of jQuery and Javascript in here, and simple CSS is here to help!

```css
html,body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

To put this in action, use a link and give it an href with the id of the element you're scrolling to:

```html
<a href="sectionOne">Section One</a>

<div id="sectionOne">
    <h2>Section One</h2>
</div>
```

Not all browsers however support the `scroll-behavior` property, in which case I'd recommend the selected answer near the top ;)

Answer (score 0):

Animate to last item with specific attribute

```
$('html').animate({
   scrollTop: $('className:last[data-id]').offset().top - 100
}, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would help `$(".element").attr("any-attribute-of-ur-elem");`
In your case it would look like: `$(".post").attr("data-id")`
And you can scrollTo that posts.
try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#button").click(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $(".post[data-id="+yourID+"]").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```