# Select list scroll to a specific option issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to do the same kind of things being done in this question : [Scroll to a specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786366/scroll-to-a-specific-div)

I have those scripts loaded and working :

```
<script src=\"./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js\"></script>
<script src=\"./js/jquery-ui.js\"></script>
<script src=\"./js/myscript.js\"></script>
```

My current PHP/HTML code :

```
echo "<select name=\"travel\" id=\"mySelect\">";
                echo "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"></option>";

                for ( $hours = 0 ; $hours <= 23 ; $hours++ ) {
                    for ( $minutes = 0 ; $minutes <= 45 ; $minutes += 15 ) {

                        echo "<option value=\"$hours:$minutes\">";
                        printf("%02d", $hours);
                        echo ":";
                        printf ("%02d", $minutes);
                        echo "</option>";
                    }
                }
echo "</select>";
```

My JS inside myscript.js :

```
    $('#mySelect').focus(function(){

    if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
    {
        $(this).data('focused',true);  
        $(this).children(':last-child').prop('selected',true);
    }

});

$('#mySelect').blur(function(){
   $(this).data('focused',false); 
});
```

It should select when I open the dropdown menu 23:45 but it keeps showing the blank value.
At the end I would like set it open the dropdown menu directly to something like 10:00 instead of blank or 00:00 so users don't have to scroll down a lot each times.

There is no errors messages so I realy don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone highlight me please?

Comment: you are using `$(this).data('focused')` but i dont see the `data` attribute in your `select` element.

Comment: you cant have the standard `select` element have a smooth scroll like that demo page you saw. However, you can pre-select the option `10:00`, when the option is pre-selected, it would be highlighted and when the user opens the dropdown it would be seen there without them having to scroll down.

Comment: @CodeGodie I need the blank option selected. Does it exist in HTML an option kind of pre-selected when someone open the dropdown menu only ? Exemple blank value as selected and the user open it and it has already scroll down to 10:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the result you desire without javascript, by simply inserting the bank `<option>` at the correct point in the list.

You can do that by checking the `$hour` and a simple boolean flag:

```
echo "<select name=\"travel\" id=\"mySelect\">";
$blankInserted = false;
for ( $hours = 0 ; $hours <= 23 ; $hours++ ) {
    for ( $minutes = 0 ; $minutes <= 45 ; $minutes += 15 ) {
        if($hours==10 && !$blankInserted){
            echo "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"></option>";
            $blankInserted = true;
        }

        echo "<option value=\"$hours:$minutes\">";
        printf("%02d", $hours);
        echo ":";
        printf ("%02d", $minutes);
        echo "</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: This is genious I didn't thought about it! I wait a bit if someone was about to post another answer. If not I check your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be to completely solve your issue using PHP by using the DateTime object:

```
// Make a DateTime object with the current date and time
$today = new DateTime();

// Make an empty array to contain the hours
$aHours = array();

// Make another DateTime object with the current date and time
$oStart = new DateTime('now');

// Set current time to midnight
$oStart->setTime(0, 0);

// Clone DateTime object (This is like 'copying' it)
$oEnd = clone $oStart;

// Add 1 day (24 hours)
$oEnd->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));

// Add each hour to an array
while ($oStart->getTimestamp() < $oEnd->getTimestamp()) {
    $aHours[] = $oStart->format('H');
    $oStart->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
}

// Create an array with quarters
$quarters = array(
    '0',
    '15',
    '30',
    '45',
);

// Get the current quarter
$currentQuarter = $today->format('i') - ($today->format('i') % 15);
```

Then to print:

```
<select name="travel" id="mySelect">
    <option value="-1">Choose a time</option>
    <?php foreach ($aHours as $hour): ?>
        <?php foreach ($quarters as $quarter): ?>
            <option value="<?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $quarter); ?>" <?= ($hour == $today->format('H') && $quarter == $currentQuarter) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?= sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hour, $quarter); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

In the above example you will generate a dropdown with all hours of a day. The current hour and quarter will be automatically selected.

Comment: I don't need it to be on current time but your code is realy interesting. I might use it later. Thank you !